# Objective C: Cell text disappears after scrolling out of screen (and back)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, identifier

I am creating a controller with a UITableview which contains 2 sections. In the second section, I have a list of users which I want to add a checkmark to the user in the list when I click on the particular row. I have an issue whereby after I click on a user and scroll the cell out of the page, the cell returns with the 'name' field BLANK (see screenshot below). I know this has to do with the way the cells are reused but am not able to get my head around the exact issue. My code is posted below. Any advise?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* ShareOnCellIdentifier = @"ShareOnholderCell";
    static NSString* WhoShouldAnswerCellIdentifier = @"WhoShouldAnswerCell";

    int row = [indexPath row];

    User *user = [self.friendsToShareWithArray objectAtIndex:row];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) 
    {

        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ShareOnCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ShareOnCellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.shareOnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:WhoShouldAnswerCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:WhoShouldAnswerCellIdentifier];
         }
        cell.textLabel.text = user.nickname;
        if (user.isSelected) 
        {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
        return cell;
    }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    User *user = [self.friendsToShareWithArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.section == 1) 
    {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            user.isSelected = NO;

        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            user.isSelected = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Example of how I create my user object

```
User *user1 = [[User alloc]init];
    user1.nickname = @"Dionis";
    user1.uid = @"1";
    user1.isSelected = NO;
```

Comment: By `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;` you meant `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;` right?

Comment: Yup that's right, silly mistake from me. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Not your answer, but you're leaking cells. Whenever you alloc/init a new cell, you also need to autorelease it. Otherwise every single table cell you create lives forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see is in the way you've implemented `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1) 
    {
        User *user = [self.friendsToShareWithArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        user.isSelected = !user.isSelected;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Deepak, thanks for your response. I changed the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method. When I tried to click on the cell, nothing happens. Do you see anything else missing?

Comment: How is the `isSelected` property defined in `User`?

Comment: I tried to add the code NSLog(@"user selected:%d",user.isSelected); in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it is always returning me the value 0. Why doesn't it change the value of the boolean 'isSelected' for me? Please see my edited qn on how I set my user in the first place?

Comment: @Deepak, thanks that works perfectly. I should have spotted that as well. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Deepak, do you mind explaining to me why my initial implementation didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this kind of issue in the past caused by not realizing that basically every time a cell comes into view in a scrollable `UITableView`, it'll be re-requested via `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  I can't see an error being made here (you're always setting the label's text), but at this point I would suggest checking the text of the label after you set it.:

```
if (!cell.textLabel.text || [[cell.textLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] isEqualToString:@""])
    NSAssert(NO, @"Bad text!");
```

Running in debug, this will "crash" at the `NSAssert` if the text is blank or nil.  Then you might be able to inspect the surrounding variables (could `user` be nil, or something like that?) and find out more.